# Is it possible to soft code sql statements?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I was told that it is possible to soft code SQL queries instead of hard coding them. Just like we parse JSON responses in Java, we can do that through an external file like below:

```
abc:[
{
sql:"selecct count(*) from some_database",
count:"100"
}]
```

Is it possible? How I can do that? Links or articles would be appreciated. I am using **Hibernate**. How can I run a SQL query through external file in Hibernate?

Comment: SQL is just text. You can pass SQL to the SQL database, where that SQL comes from, the database won't care.

Comment: Well, what part are you asking about? Reading files? Passing queries to a database? Something else?

Comment: I'm not familiar with standard Java SQL interfaces, but in all reasonable SQL APIs there's the ability to have substitution variables in query statements.  You need to read the documentation for your toolset.

Comment: Running queries through an external file.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't make your queries web-accessible. an attacker can learn a huge amount about your application and its backend if you expose your queries to them. Instead use a local file, resource, or a webservice deployed inside your network (not on the public facing web server). Personally I'd just use an XML file.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "external file".  The only "external file" that SQL knows about is the SQL database file.  For anything else you must do the connecting.

Comment: External file can be JSON file or XML that contains SQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java, try using [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org).

SQL statements are placed in a resource XML file and code references the queries by name.  This allows you to edit the XML when details of the schema change, possibly without modifying the code that consumes them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

for instance in a resource bundle:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle();
PreparedStatement psmt = connection.prepareStatement(bundle.getString("users.query"));
....
```

Or any other string for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Store the SQL statements in variables, or return them from a function if you want to dynamically add variables to the SQL statements themselves.

Wherever you normally put an SQL query as a string, just put the variable, or function call instead.